# Finding a linear transformation $T$ such that $T(v) \cap n(T) \neq \lbrace 0 \rbrace$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My professor gave us this problem as a final review, and I am confused what it is asking. If someone could put into words what the question is, that would be helpful.

> Give an example of a linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow V$  such that $T(V) \cap n(T) \neq \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, where $n(T)$ means the nullspace.

We solved this using matrices... And it seem to me, that it is asking if there is a linear transformation for which the elements in the image, and the null space share an element in common. Would any element of the nullspace be a member of both?

Comment: Rather than $T(v)$, I think that you mean to write $T(V)$, which is the *image set* or *range* of the transformation:  $\{ T(v) \mid v \in V \}$.

Comment: yes, @SammyBlack edit made, thanks.

Comment: What is the command to get that box?

Comment: Start the line with `>!`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're thinking the right things.  Here's how I conceptualize it.

Suppose that you have a vector in $v \in T(V) \cap n(T)$.  Since $v \in n(T)$, you know that $T(v) = 0$ and since $v \in T(V)$, you know that there is some $u \in V$ (not necessarily unique) such that $T(u) = v$.  Like this:
$$
u \overset{T}{\longmapsto} v \overset{T}{\longmapsto} 0
$$

So you have to think about a linear transformation $T$ that *eventually* sends a vector to zero (after **two** applications of $T$ but not after one).

The simplest example that I can think of:

> In the standard basis for $\Bbb{R}^2$, $u = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $v = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, and $[T] = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: In fact the example you give here is the unique building block for *all* examples of such transformations, in the sense that for any $v \neq 0$ in the intersection and any preimage $u$ of $v$, we can choose a basis $(E_i)$ for which $E_1 = u$ and $E_2 = v$; in particular the upper-left $2 \times 2$ minor of the matrix representation $[T]$ of $T$ w.r.t. $(E_i)$ is $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. (In fact, we can choose $(E_i)$ so that [T] is in Jordan Normal Form, provided the eigenvalues lie in the underlying field or that we are happy to pass to some larger field.) (+1)

Comment: Certainly.  :-) $\,      $

Comment: I see you were at Oregon, what years were you there? I did my undergrad work there and finished in '05.

Answer (score 3):

An example for this is the following map.

Define $T: V \to V $ such that for $v$ in the basis of $V$

$T(v) =\begin{cases} 0 & if \text{ i is even} \\ v_{i-1} & if \text{ i is odd}
\end{cases} $

the null pace of $T$ is the set of all $v_i$ for $i$ even and $T(V)$ is also the same set.

$\implies T(V) \cap n(T) = $set of $v_i$ for $i$ even.

Comment: It is correct *in spirit* though.  In fact, a small tweak makes it a nice answer.  Let $\Bbb{N}$ index the basis of a vector space and map $v_i \mapsto 0$ if $i$ is even, $v_i \mapsto v_{i-1}$ if $i$ is odd.  This is the countable direct sum of the $2 \times 2$ Jordan block in my example.

Comment: This is what I was writing but made mistake in typing. I had some other thing in mind.

Comment: I have edited the answer.

Comment: Cheers, this answer is quite nice! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation is correct.

Re your question, in general, elements of the null space are not in the image. For example, for any vector space $V$, every element is in the null space of the zero map, but only $0$ is the image.

We can produce examples of transformations with nontrivial intersection deductively, and in fact an easy line of reasoning gives us a characterization of such transformations.

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and $T$ a linear transformation $V \ to V$. Since the intersection $T(V) \cap n(T)$ is nontrivial, so is $n(T)$, and hence $T$ has at least one zero eigenvalue. Now, consider the Jordan Canonical Form $[T]$ of $T$:

**Case 1** If all of the Jordan blocks of $[T]$ of eigenvalue $0$ have size $1 \times 1$, say there are $k$ of them, then (after possibly reordering the blocks) $[T]$ has the form $A \oplus 0_{k \times k}$, where $A$ is an invertible $(n - k) \times (n - k)$ matrix. (In order to talk about the Jordan Canonical Form this way, we must be willing to work in some extension of the underlying field $\mathbb{F}$ of $V$ if necessary, but this poses no problem here, as it doesn't affect our conclusions.) With respect to the given basis $(E_a)$, we have $T(V) = \langle E_1, \ldots, E_{n - k} \rangle$ and $n(T) = \langle E_{n - k + 1}, \ldots, E_n \rangle$, and so the intersection is trivial.

**Case 2** Suppose $[T]$ has a Jordan block $J$ of eigenvalue $0$ of larger size, say, $m \times m$. Then, as a map $\mathbb{F}^m \to \mathbb{F}^m$, in the standard basis $(E_1, \ldots, E_m)$ we have $J(\mathbb{F}^m) = \langle E_1, \ldots, E_{m - 1} \rangle$ and $n(J) = \langle E_1 \rangle$, so the intersection is $\langle E_1 \rangle$. Passing back to $[T]$ itself, by virtue of how the Jordan Canonical Form behaves (namely, it is a decomposition into a direct sum of linear transformations), the intersection for $J$ is a subset of the intersection for $T$. In particular, each such Jordan block, that is each matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 &   & & & \\
                   & 0 & 1 & & & \\
                   &   & \ddots & \ddots & & \\
                   &   &        &      \ddots & 1 & \\ 
                   &   &        &        & 0 & 1 \\
                   &   &        &        &   & 0
\end{pmatrix},$$ regarded as a linear transformation of $\mathbb{F}^m$, is itself an example of a linear transformation for which the intersection is nontrivial.

We can conclude the following:

**Proposition** Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and $T$ a linear transformation $V \to V$. Then, the intersection $T(V) \cap n(T)$ is nontrivial iff the Jordan Canonical Form $[T]$ of $T$ contains a block of eigenvalue $0$ and size at least $2$. Moreover, the number of such blocks in $[T]$ is $\dim (T(V) \cap n(T))$.

**Remark** By the Rank-Nullity Theorem, the dimension of the intersection must satisfy
$$\dim (T(V) \cap n(T)) \leq \left\lfloor \frac{\dim V}{2} \right\rfloor.$$